# Test adUnit works but my own adUnit wont work (react-native-admob)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob

hi guys im new to react native. im using react-native-admob

```
<AdMobBanner
   adSize="smartBanner"
   adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
   testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
   onAdFailedToLoad={(error) => console.log(error)}
/>
```

the adUnitID im using is for testing and it works. But if I use my adUnitID it wont show anything in the app

how to resolve this, any ideas? :)

additional info:
-I also tried to delete the testDevices and onAdFailedToLoad and nothing works.
-on the console log it shows "Internal error, an invalid response was received from the ad server."